# HTML source code in TreeView C#

Tags: c#, html, dom, treeview

I'm writing a C# project and i have to get the HTML source code from a given website and show it in a TreeView control(each html tag should be a node).

I've already placed a web browser component, i navigate to the site but i'm having trouble writing the recursive function to get the HTML and create the TreeView out of it.

My google searches didn't provide any helpful solutions. Can anyone help me with any tips, articles or even examples? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string url = "http://www.google.com";
    wb.Navigate(url);  
}
TreeView tv = new TreeView();
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    if (wb.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        tv.Nodes.Add(LoadNode(wb.Document.Body));
}
private TreeNode LoadNode(HtmlElement htmlElm)
{
    TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(htmlElm.TagName);
    for (int i = 0; i < htmlElm.Children.Count; i++)
        tn.Nodes.Add(LoadNode(htmlElm.Children[i]));
    return tn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Is there any way to also get head html and not only the body?

Comment: You can use "wb.Document.Body.Parent" instead of "wb.Document.Body"

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - its great for parsing Html in code and you can use Linq to navigate through all the html elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it must not contain any "outside" libraries.